# Sticky footer with CSS Layout Template Module?

Tags: jquery, html, css, templates, sticky-footer

I'm currently looking into the JQuery library for [CSS Layout Template module](http://code.google.com/p/css-template-layout/)

Is it possible to define the height of a placeholder with *?
Meaning it will push content down if it has to, or fill up any remaining space if the complete content is less then the view port.

This would be really nice to make the whole [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) thing much easier and robust.

Comment: As a clarification, the emphasis lays on the Layout module, not the JQuery library. Because no browsers support the module yet (it's part of the CSS3 specs) I'm using the JQuery fix as a workaround to be able to test it, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Boris,

I'm not that familiar with JQuery but I can give you the JavaScript for this if you want it?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I'm not really looking for any sticky footer scripts. I was just wondering if the CSS Layout Template Module would make a sticky footer with pure css possible. Because this layout is not supported yet in most (any?) browsers I'm currently doing it with the JQuery implementation, but that's just a work around until the layout is supported

Comment: I put out a blog there on a CSS solution to this for ASP.NET sites with master pages. It turned out that there was still a problem with one of the two main browsers but I think in the comments section, someone offered a fix (haven's tested it):

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/09/10/CSS-Sticky-Footer-for-ASPNET-Master-Page.aspx